# SQL Math update performance optimizing

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, math

I am running simple update over >70 Mio. Records (MS-SQL Server 2008)

```
UPDATE T1 SET COSTS=AMOUNT*0.003
```

and it takes up to 8 Hours.

Is there an simple "cheap" way to improve math performance of updates like this?

And since there is no WHERE clause or compares, just multiply every record with value, creating an INDEX will have no  effect... or?

Thank you very much in advance for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Writing 70 Mio rows does take time. Adding an index would make things even worse, because the index has to be updated along with the table.

Is this update really necessary? Can't you solve the task with a view or computed column or whatever?

Comment: This is transactions database - it contains records over money transfers caused from buyers. In Germany there is the possibility to just "trust" the buyer - called ELV-online which leads sometimes for transaction to be rejected since there is not enough money in the account. The alternative is to use the EC-Cash which is to check the account if there is enough money to pay... for this one you have to pay the bank for this information and it is 0.3 % from transaction ammount (or at least 0.08 EUR). So I need to compare transaction types on the caused costs - what if every trx is EC-Cash

Answer (score 1):

I fully agree with the above comments.  The issue is not match calculations, instead it is the I/O of the database engine.

I just want to suggested computed columns.  You can add a "virtual" column to the table that is calculated from other values in the same row.  This means that you might be able to dispense with the update altogether.  Just alter the table to add a column:

```
alter table add costs_new as amount * 0.03.
```

To keep the current name, you need to change the old name:

```
exec sp_rename 't1.costs', 'costs_old', 'column';
alter table add costs as amount*0.03;
```

This may be a quick-and-dirty way to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will check and give feedback (if this is faster than my approach)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not math (calculation of that value), but the fact that sql server needs to read every record and write it to the HDD again. Since calculation itself is really cheap, you can just have `costs` as calculated field wherever you need it.

Comment: Many thanks! That is what i was afraid of... I have a test system using RAID0 over SSDs - not for productive work, but for testing purpouses only - I will copy the database there and test it